# XSL all records from XML

Tags: xml, xslt

i have for example this source XML:

```
<People>
   <Person Name="NameOne"/>
   <Person Name="NameTwo"/>
</People>
```

I have this XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1250"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:for-each select="People">  
        <Names> 
                <Human><xsl:value-of select="Person/@Name"/></Human>
        </Names>
     </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have this XML output:

```
<Names> 
     <Human>NameOne</Human>
</Names>
```

But i need this output with all records:

```
<Names> 
     <Human>NameOne</Human>
     <Human>NameTwo</Human>
</Names>
```

Have you got any ideas please?

Comment: +1 for a good documented question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you are iterating over **People** elements

```
<xsl:for-each select="People">
```

But you only have one **People** element in your XML. You need to "match" the **People** element, then iterate over the **Person** elements

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="People">
    <Names> 
        <xsl:for-each select="Person">  
            <Human><xsl:value-of select="@Name"/></Human>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </Names>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or better still, use a fully template approach without **xsl:for-each**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="People">
    <Names> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Person" /> 
    </Names>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Person">
    <Human><xsl:value-of select="@Name"/></Human>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code if you wanna use for-each

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Names> 
    <xsl:for-each select="People/Person">            
            <Human><xsl:value-of select="@Name"/></Human>
    </xsl:for-each> 
    </Names>
</xsl:template>
```